# How to build a python asyncio base coroutine?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

Its easy to create a coroutine that calls some other coroutine, but if for example i want to create a coroutine that doesn't block, how do I do that? Should I launch a thread that does that calculation and then capture the callback somehow?

Looking at the asyncio.sleep implementation they do that calling the loop to return later on time instead of a "real" sleep

I have come to this but its still not working.

```py
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures


def inner_task(num_1, num_2):
    return num_1 ** num_2


async def exp_coroutine(num_1, num_2):

    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, inner_task, num_1, num_2)


async def my_base_coroutine(num_1, num_2):
    results = await exp_coroutine(num_1, num_2)
    print(results)
    return results


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(my_base_coroutine(23, 876))
loop.create_task(my_base_coroutine(23, 1))
loop.create_task(my_base_coroutine(23, 35))

tasks = asyncio.Task.all_tasks()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```

Currently I am getting the results exactly how they are asked from and would expect the easier calculations first.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Maybe you should just try with larger numbers to reliably affect the order. `23**876` takes very little time for Python to calculate, so maybe it finishes before the second calculation is submitted to the thread pool.

Comment: You are right raising the calculation shows that its correct, thanks!!

Comment: Or toss in a random sleep.

Comment: Also note that you aren't really creating a coroutine that doesn't block - you are merely hiding the blocking through the use of a thread pool. The true power of asyncio coroutines comes from **not** using threads, but suspending execution at the point where a sync call would normally block. See, for example, [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) for an example of what asyncio does. (The lecture uses the older `yield from` syntax instead of `await` - but that doesn't matter, they do the exact same thing under the hood.)